# Entity Framework Database First Relation Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm still new to Entity Framework and I'm having some trouble with my actual project.

First I set up my database.

Table1:

```
CREATE TABLE [EAM].[TB_Hardware] 
(
    [Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [HWName]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Standort] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [IdArt]    INT           NULL,
    [Mitarbeiternummer] INT  NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Hardware] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [EAM_FG],
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Hardware_MaID] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([Mitarbeiternummer]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TB_Mitarbeiter] ([Mitarbeiternummer])
);
```

Table2:

```
CREATE TABLE [EAM].[TB_Netzwerk] 
(
    [Id]           INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NetzwerkName] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [idArt]        INT           NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Netzwerk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [EAM_FG],
);
```

Now I need a relation table for these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [EAM].[TB_Hardware_zu_Netzwerk] 
(
    [IDHardware] INT NULL,
    [IDNetzwerk] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Zuordnung_HWNW_Hardware] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDHardware]) REFERENCES [EAM].[TB_Hardware] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Zuordnung_HWNW_Netzwerk] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDNetzwerk]) REFERENCES [EAM].[TB_Netzwerk] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Zuordnung_HWNW] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([IDHardware] ASC, [IDNetzwerk] ASC) ON [EAM_FG]
) ON [EAM_FG];
```

After the database was set up I created an ASP.NET MVC project with EF. I created my model with database first and chose the `EAM` schema.

I was expecting that the relation table would be created the same way like the other tables. But it did not.

The table is not shown in the model.

Why not, and how can I get this table to my MVC project?

Comment: I expect you mean the model class by the table, since table you have created manually. Well, what would be the purpose of such N:M model?You will have just N model with Ms property (multiple Ms) and M model with Ns property. And that's it. I don't understand why you would need the explicit N:M model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i know now what the problem is:

i changed my Create Table to:

```
CREATE TABLE [EAM].[TB_Hardware_zu_Netzwerk] (
[IDHardware] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [EAM].[TB_Hardware] ([ID]),
[IDNetzwerk] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [EAM].[TB_Netzwerk] ([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [IX_Zuordnung_HWNW] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([IDHardware] ASC, [IDNetzwerk] ASC) ON [EAM_FG]) ON [EAM_FG]
```

Now i have my Navigation Properties. :)